# Gathering energy from other people to create an energy attack, which was the first anime to feature it?

Tags: tropes

In Black Clover in one of the last episodes (I dont recall if it was #118 or #117) Litch the elf leader gathers energy from the other elfs to create an energy attack, similar to Goku's genki dama, to be more precise more similar to Trunks's "Genki Dama" "Sword of Hope", since the energy is gathered in the sword in both cases. Are these 2 animes the only ones who featured this idea?

Which was the first anime to feature the idea of gathering energy from other people to create an energy attack?

Comment: I know *EarthBound* did the same thing in 1994, but I don't know whether that predates DBZ's "shared energy" attacks. It's also not an anime; just an interesting side note.

Comment: Please only tag questions with series that it is specifically about and not add them for the sake of adding them because they are tangentially related.